# update a post with wp_update_post

Tags: wp-update-post

I am using a wp_update_post to change the status of a post from published to pending using 
`wp_update_post(
   array(
       'ID'           => $post_id,
       'post_status'  => 'Pending',
   )
);`

with code I can change the status but when I want to save and publish the post from admin area after chaning the status and hit publish, there is some king of loop is happening and nothing will be saved after waiting several minutes post update will be failed.

Comment: Please provide more of the code you're using like the action you hooked on.

Comment: add_action( 'init', array($this, 'my_custom_function') );
this is the hook I am using when updating the post

Comment: Update your question with that and the contents of `my_custom_function()`.

Comment: this function is too big

Comment: Hard to help then